# How to can I manipulate the shadow root without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs3, queryselector, shadow-root

I have some ui elements from a third party that I want to manipulate to set a different styling.

First I wrote a explicit css rule which obviously did not do anything.

Currently I am using this hack:

```
mounted() {
  setTimeout(
      function () {
              document
                 .querySelector("#wrapper")
                 .shadowRoot.querySelector(".div-in-shadow-root")
                 .setAttribute("style", "box-shadow:none");
    }.bind(this),
    1000
  );
}
```

This leads to some flickering in the UI that looks trashy.

Is there any better solution to do this?

Comment: probably no need for the 1000 ms, can be 0. But you will always be changing DOM **after** it was displayed. Might be possible to create your own component with ``extends customElements.get("that-component")`` and work on its shadowDOM **before** it is displayed.

Comment: Why do you even need that in the first place? Can't you use a regular conditional on the class itself? Also, since you're using Vue3, give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74789390/8816585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, that there is only the possibility to change the styling via css, if the developer of the third party ui element allows it through the `part` property.

If this is the case, this can be addressed like this:

```css
#wrapper::part(definedPartName) {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```